# When do I attack if complete my battle line with a card stolen by Venemous Creeps?

Tags: chaos-marauders

Playing a green card ends the turn so do I attack the turn I play the Venemous Creeps, or the following turn?

Comment: Welcome to B&CG!  Good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Venemous Creeps section of the [Chaos Marauders card reference](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/chaos-marauders/PDF/chaos-marauders-card-ref-en.pdf):

> If a player completes a battle line with a stolen card, he may still
>   attack an opponent’s battle line as normal.

So the normal rules apply, that is to say: "As soon as a battle line has been completed, it can attack any opponent’s incomplete battle line" [assuming the completed battle line is strong enough].

Therefore, yes, you do attack on the current turn, not the next turn.